# Show $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1-x^{a \log(n)}) =0$ when $a <\frac{-1}{\log(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

I'd like to show that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1-x^{a \log(n)}) =1$$ when $a >\frac{-1}{\log(x)}$ and
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1-x^{a \log(n)}) =0$$ when $a <\frac{-1}{\log(x)}$

Where $x \in (0,1)$. I have managed to show the first limit using $a = \frac{-1}{\log(x)}+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$. However this approach did not work for the second one (taking $a = \frac{-1}{\log(x)}-\epsilon$).

My idea was since we want the limit to be $0$, we would want $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x ^{a\log(n)}=1$. This only happens when $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a \log(n) = 0$. Substituting $a = \frac{-1}{\log(x)}-\epsilon$ does not help solving this limit though. I was wondering if someone maybe could give me a hint on how to approach this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems a bit odd:  Since $\log n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, if $x^a > 1$  then your limit is $-\infty$.  If $x^a = 1$ the limit is $0$ (as are all intermediate terms), and if $x^a < 1$ the limit is $1$.  Is there something missing from the question?

Answer (score 1):

When $0 < x < 1$ then
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\big( 1 - x^{a\log n} \big) = \left\{
\begin{array} & 0 & \text{if } a = 0 \\
1 & \text{if } a > 0 \\
-\infty & \text{if } a < 0
\end{array}
\right.
\end{aligned}